# Hot Reload only works with changes in App.js

Tags: react-native, expo, hot-reload

Hot reload feature on expo only seems to work when I modify and save App.js.

If I save my changes on a different file, nothing happens. If a change a different file, save it, and then save App.js as well to hot reload the changes, the app refreshes but the changes to the external file aren't there.

I've already checked my network, ran under the tunnel configuration and nothing really seemed to work. I was wondering if anyone else is having a similar issue.

Comment: read this page for more info on how fast refresh works: https://reactnative.dev/docs/fast-refresh

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that made hot reload work was placing the file in the same directory as App.js. I've had the same issue and I couldn't find any other solutions either. Before I figured this out I always had to refresh the server with `expo start -c --tunnel`. Without the `-c` flag it didn't refresh my custom components.